# I am trying to move some data to the next activity but am getting some errors on my putExtra. The code is shown below

Tags: kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT0J3.png)

Am trying to pass data from one activity to another

Comment: What is the type of the variable you are passing?

Comment: @Nyariki - Welcome to SO.Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)